# share target multiple images windows 8

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have implemented a share target contract to share multiple photos; I can get the shared image list with the folderRelativeID but I need to get the files full path so I can share it with my program.

can this be done?

I'm using HTML/Javascript and c# so knowing the full path in either location will be fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is you project folder, use:

```
<img id="mainImg2" src="ms-appdata:///Local//bckgrnd.jpg" />
```